# Use concatenated name to filter results but don't display name in table

Tags: mysql, filter, concatenation

I need to produce the following:

```
Comp No    Year Purchased
=========================

11111       2008
22222       2007
33333       2008
44444       2006
```

But I need to exclude some results based on a concatenated name.  And I can't have the name listed in the result.  This is my code:

```
SELECT 
Comp_Num,
YEAR (Comp_PurchaseDate) AS 'Year Purchased',
CONCAT(Emp_First, ' ', Emp_Last) as 'Name'
FROM Computer
JOIN Hire using (Comp_Num)
JOIN employee using (Emp_Num)
ORDER BY Comp_Num;
```

It produces:

```
Comp No    Year Purchased   Name
================================

11111       2008            AAA
22222       2007            BBB
33333       2008            CCC
44444       2006            DDD
```

The concatenated name is used to filter out results, eg:

```
WHERE ('Name' <> 'AAA' AND
        Name' <> 'DDD')
```

How do I create the concatenated name to filter out results without displaying the column?  The concatenate doesn't work without "as 'name' ".

And how do I use the concatenated name to filter?  Can I still use Where?  Or is there another clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define the expression in the `WHERE` clause instead:

```
SELECT 
Comp_Num,
YEAR (Comp_PurchaseDate) AS `Year Purchased`
FROM Computer
JOIN Hire using (Comp_Num)
JOIN employee using (Emp_Num)
WHERE (CONCAT(Emp_First, ' ', Emp_Last) <> 'AAA' AND
       CONCAT(Emp_First, ' ', Emp_Last) <> 'DDD')
ORDER BY Comp_Num;
```

Also Read: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you @Madhur Bhaiya.  I also need to filter                   
                                                                                                 
Comp_PurchaseDate <= 2008.

Comment: I thought it would go in the where clause but this just produces an empty table.

Comment: @ppines use `where YEAR (Comp_PurchaseDate) <= 2008`.

Comment: Fabulous!  Thanks again @Madhur Bhaiya

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative to Madhur's two `CONCAT()` calls is to use `NOT IN ()` and only concatenate once.

```
SELECT Comp_Num,
    YEAR (Comp_PurchaseDate) AS `Year Purchased`
FROM Computer
JOIN Hire USING Comp_Num
JOIN employee USING Emp_Num
WHERE CONCAT(Emp_First, ' ', Emp_Last) NOT IN ('AAA','DDD')
ORDER BY Comp_Num
```